# Prevent webworkers from using IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker

I'm working on an application where I have multiple webworkers running together. These webworkers are developed by third parties, and are not trusted. They provide postmessage APIs to each other.

I would like to enable the webworkers to have safe access to local storage. IndexedDB is the standard choice, however I need to ensure that a malicious webworker cannot interfere with the data of another webworker.

My original idea was that I could 'domain' each webworker somehow. Each one gets access to its own piece of IndexedDB, and cannot see the storage put in other pieces by other webworkers. At the moment, I do not believe this is possible since I need the workers to exist together in one iframe.

My next idea was to have a single, trusted webworker that has IndexedDB access, and set up sandbox rules for all of the other webworkers such that they can't use IndexedDB at all, but instead must communicate with the API of the trusted webworker to store and retrieve local data. My current understanding is that I can get this to work if I use two iframes, where the first iframe has access to IndexedDB and runs the trusted webworker, and the second iframe is in a different domain where non-malicious webworkers know not to use the storage.

I am not a huge fan of the two iframe solution - it's complex, has performance overheads, and requires webworker devs to know they can't safely use localstorage even though they actually have access - and I'm looking for a better way to sandbox specific  webworkers away from indexeddb.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about how the Workers are initiated? i.e where is the call to `new Worker()` being made, by whom, how much control do you have over the whole process? One alternative to the 2 iframes with maybe a bit less burden would be to start your workers from a `data:` URL, e.g `new Worker(\`data:text/javascript,importScripts("${THE_WORKER_URL}");\`)`. This would prevent the loaded script from accessing IDB altogether, and so your "trusted" worker would have to manage everything.

Comment: The worker is being created from a blob:

`let url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob[workerCode])); return new Worker(url)`.

Can you link to some documentation about how your method prevents the loaded script from accessing IDB?

Comment: `data:` URLs make "opaque" origins, so starting your worker with such an URL will [make your worker's origin opaque](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#script-settings-for-workers:concept-origin-opaque). IDB doesn't work with opaque origins: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-open (step 4). Note that starting your Worker with a `blob:` URL on the other hand will make it share the origin with its owner.